# Comparing two arrays of pixel values, and store any matches

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

I want to compare the pixel values of two images, which I have stored in arrays.

Suppose the arrays are `A` and `B`. I want to compare the elements one by one, and if `A[l] == B[k]`, then I want to store the match as a key value-pair in a third array, `C`, like so: `C[l] = k`.

Since the arrays are naturally quite large, the solution needs to finish within a reasonable amount of time (minutes) on a Core 2 Duo system.

Comment: I took the images of around 1024 *720 images and yes I am able to read the images and then concert the 2d array into 1d array

Comment: Also I am not having threading processor,  can you give me full code , if not then  already for loop , mine code is running for around 8

Comment: Okay, I've re-read your question and realized I don't understand it at all. Can you give a *small* example of what you want?

Comment: Sorry for not this , question is this I want to compare two pictures 1d array and if both are having the same element then store the address in new array

Comment: Now read the above question also, please

Comment: Did you mean `A(l) == B(l)` (comparing the first pixel in `A` to the first pixel in `B`, for example), or are you comparing `A(l)` to *each* element in `B`?

Comment: Consider a(1) = 567 , then finding the b(j) = 567 then storing c(1) = j , the index.   By the way I have converted the images into 1d array from the 2d

Comment: Okay... now what if there are multiple `567` values in `B`? Do you want all of them? Just the first? Just the last?

Comment: Just the one value .

Comment: First one will be preferred

Comment: If it's not having the match store value = 0 in array c

Comment: How many distinct values do your arrays `A` and `B` have? Are they 8-bit images with values from `0..255`, or double arrays with continuous values?

Comment: Rgb image uint 8 format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work in under a second for `1024*720` matrices:

```
A = randi(255,737280,1);
B = randi(255,737280,1);
C = zeros(size(A));

[b_vals, b_inds] = unique(B,'first');
for l = 1:numel(b_vals)
   C(A == b_vals(l)) = b_inds(l);
end
```

First we find the unique values of `B` and the indices of the first occurrences of these values.

```
[b_vals, b_inds] = unique(B,'first');
```

We know that there can be no more than 256 unique values in a uint8 array, so we've reduced our loop from `1024*720` iterations to just `256` iterations.

We also know that for each occurrence of a particular value, say `209`, in `A`, those locations in `C` will all have the same value: the location of the first occurrence of `209` in `B`, so we can set all of them at once. First we get locations of all of the occurrences of `b_vals(l)` in `A`:

```
A == b_vals(l)
```

then use that mask as a logical index into `C`.

```
C(A == b_vals(l))
```

All of these values will be equal to the corresponding index in `B`:

```
   C(A == b_vals(l)) = b_inds(l);
```

---

Here is the updated code to consider *all* of the indices of a value in `B` (or at least as many as are necessary). If there are more occurrences of a value in `A` than in `B`, the indices wrap.

```
A = randi(255,737280,1);
B = randi(255,737280,1);
C = zeros(size(A));

b_vals = unique(B);
for l = 1:numel(b_vals)
    b_inds = find(B==b_vals(l));    %// find the indices of each unique value in B
    a_inds = find(A==b_vals(l));    %// find the indices of each unique value in A
        %// in case the length of a_inds is greater than the length of b_inds
        %// duplicate b_inds until it is larger (or equal)
    b_inds = repmat(b_inds,[ceil(numel(a_inds)/numel(b_inds)),1]);
        %// truncate b_inds to be the same length as a_inds (if necessary) and
        %// put b_inds into the proper places in C
    C(a_inds) = b_inds(1:numel(a_inds));
end
```

I haven't fully tested this code, but from my small samples it seems to work properly and on the full-size case, it only takes about twice as long as the previous code, or less than 2 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Note that I only used `l` as the variable name to be consistent with what you're doing. Personally, I tend to get `l` confused with `1` in my code.

Comment: thanks , can you explain this procedure a little  bit , please dear

Comment: @user5711858 Is that clear, or do you want me to give a concrete example?

Comment: awesome man you are clearely awesome, can you just help me more, if for example i found out   
a(i) == b(j) , so for next comparison the index of b should start from jth postion , please bear this .

Comment: @user5711858 This is far more complex. You are no longer setting all of the instances of a value in `A` to the same index, so you can't do it all at once. You've also got the problem of having more instances of a value in `A` than in `B`. If you've only got 5 instances in `B`, what index do you give the 6th occurrence in `A`?

Comment: sir, it's like repeating loop , after 5 it again initializes to 1, and goes on counting  it's like the loop is running like this 1 -> 5 , than again same

Comment: This will have to be a separate question. As I said, it's much more complex and I'm not sure it can be done quickly. Please open a new question with all of the requirements and I'll try to think of a way to do it efficiently.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got something, but it isn't tested. Give me a minute.

Comment: sir i will surely , was modifying the code , sorry for the delay

Comment: @user5711858 Did the updated code work for you, or were you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your question correctly, you want for each value of l=1:length(A) the (first) index k into B so that `A(l) == B(k)`. Then:

`C = arrayfun(@(val) find(B==val, 1, 'first'), A)`

could give you your solution, as long as you're sure that every element will have a match. The above solution would fail otherwise, complaning that the function returned a non-scalar (because find would return [] if no match is found). You have two options:

- Using a cell array to store the result instead of a numeric array. You would need to call arrayfun with `'UniformOutput', false` at the end. Then, the values of A without matches in B would be those for which `isempty(C{i})` is true.
- Providing a default value for an index into A with no matches in B (e.g. 0 or NaN). I'm not sure about this one, but I think that you would need to add `'ErrorHandler', @(~,~) NaN` to the arrayfun call. The error handler is a function that gets called when the function passed to arrayfun fails, and may either rethrow the error or compute a substitute value. Thus the `@(~,~) NaN`. I am not sure that it would work, however, since in this case the error is in arrayfun and not in the passed function, but you can try it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the images in arrays A & B

```
idx = A == B;
C = zeros(size(A));
C(idx) = A(idx);
```